# How do I install a tar.gz file?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)

I have aircrack.tar.gz file in my disk drive (not installed). I wanna install it via terminal. Please let me know how to install this file.#

i got.
manpages
packages
patches 
scripts
 src 
test
 AUTHORS 
ChangeLog 
common.mak 
evalrev 
INSTALLING
LICENSE 
LICENSE.OpenSSL 
Makefile
 patchchk 
README
 VERSION
.
.
WHAT CEL I DO now please give me ful process.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.1
make
make install
```

That's it.

Comment: what does this do , I cannot memorize it  -zxvf?

Answer (score 0):

A .tar.gz is an archive. You can extract its files with:

```
gunzip filename.tar.gz

tar -xf filename.tar
```

Maybe you could post what you extract of your tar.gz file.
It could be a *.deb archive or a make-file with installation files.