# Where does ttar.gz have to be located at installation?

Tags: boot

I want to install `boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz` to repair my computer as it doesn't boot (only get the "grub rescue" prompt). Now booted on a live USB Ubuntu 11.10.

Wanted to follow the below steps (found in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154302/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-file))

```
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz.
cd aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
make
make install
```

After typing the first line, this is the output in the Terminal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tar -zxvf boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz
tar (child): boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Does this have to do with the location of the tar.gz? 
I downloaded it to the Downloads directory, and located it in the Archive Manager, which shows it's under the root.

Please help with step-by-step solution.

UPDATE: Terminal output after `cd boot-repair_3.193.7.orig`as per Seth's suggestion:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tar -zxvf boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz
.gitignore
usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/boot-repair.png
usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/os-uninstaller.png
usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/sw/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/tl/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ug/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ur/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/yi/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/fil/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ht/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/mt/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/boot-sav.mo
usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_boot-repair.py
usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_os-uninstaller.py
usr/share/doc/boot-repair/changelog.gz
usr/share/doc/boot-sav/changelog.gz
usr/share/doc/clean-ubiquity/changelog.gz
usr/share/doc/os-uninstaller/changelog.gz
usr/share/applications/boot-repair.desktop
usr/share/applications/os-uninstaller.desktop
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-init.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-actions.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-tab-grub.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-dummy.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-actions-purge.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-translations.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/bis.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-tab-other.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/boot-repair-gui.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/boot-sav.glade
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-scan.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/bs-init.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-actions-grub.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/bs-common.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-tab-loca.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-tab-mbr.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/packconfig.png
usr/share/boot-sav/removegrub.png
usr/share/boot-sav/boot-repair.png
usr/share/boot-sav/boot-repair.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/boot-repair-actions.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/boot-repair-translations.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/os-uninstaller.png
usr/share/boot-sav/os-uninstaller.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/os-uninstaller-actions.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/os-uninstaller-gui.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/os-uninstaller-translations.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-raid-lvm.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-tab-main.sh
usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh
usr/bin/cleanubiquityafter
usr/bin/cleanubiquitybefore
usr/bin/os-uninstaller
usr/bin/boot-repair
etc/apport/crashdb.conf.d/os-uninstaller-crashdb.conf
etc/apport/crashdb.conf.d/boot-repair-crashdb.conf
docs/cleanubiquityafter.8
docs/cleanubiquitybefore.8
docs/os-uninstaller.8
docs/boot-repair.8
usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/
usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/sw/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/tl/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ug/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ur/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/yi/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/fil/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ht/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/mt/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/
usr/share/locale/af/
usr/share/locale/ar/
usr/share/locale/ast/
usr/share/locale/az/
usr/share/locale/be/
usr/share/locale/bg/
usr/share/locale/bn/
usr/share/locale/bs/
usr/share/locale/ca/
usr/share/locale/ckb/
usr/share/locale/cs/
usr/share/locale/da/
usr/share/locale/de/
usr/share/locale/el/
usr/share/locale/en_AU/
usr/share/locale/en_CA/
usr/share/locale/en_GB/
usr/share/locale/eo/
usr/share/locale/es/
usr/share/locale/et/
usr/share/locale/eu/
usr/share/locale/fa/
usr/share/locale/fi/
usr/share/locale/nn/
usr/share/locale/oc/
usr/share/locale/pl/
usr/share/locale/pt/
usr/share/locale/pt_BR/
usr/share/locale/ro/
usr/share/locale/ru/
usr/share/locale/sk/
usr/share/locale/sl/
usr/share/locale/sq/
usr/share/locale/sr/
usr/share/locale/sv/
usr/share/locale/sw/
usr/share/locale/ta/
usr/share/locale/te/
usr/share/locale/th/
usr/share/locale/tl/
usr/share/locale/tr/
usr/share/locale/ug/
usr/share/locale/uk/
usr/share/locale/ur/
usr/share/locale/uz/
usr/share/locale/vi/
usr/share/locale/yi/
usr/share/locale/zh_CN/
usr/share/locale/zh_HK/
usr/share/locale/zh_TW/
usr/share/locale/fil/
usr/share/locale/fr/
usr/share/locale/ga/
usr/share/locale/gl/
usr/share/locale/gu/
usr/share/locale/he/
usr/share/locale/hi/
usr/share/locale/hr/
usr/share/locale/ht/
usr/share/locale/hu/
usr/share/locale/hy/
usr/share/locale/id/
usr/share/locale/is/
usr/share/locale/it/
usr/share/locale/ja/
usr/share/locale/ka/
usr/share/locale/kn/
usr/share/locale/ko/
usr/share/locale/lt/
usr/share/locale/lv/
usr/share/locale/mg/
usr/share/locale/mk/
usr/share/locale/ms/
usr/share/locale/mt/
usr/share/locale/nb/
usr/share/locale/nl/
usr/share/icons/hicolor/
usr/share/apport/package-hooks/
usr/share/doc/boot-repair/
usr/share/doc/boot-sav/
usr/share/doc/clean-ubiquity/
usr/share/doc/os-uninstaller/
usr/share/locale/
usr/share/applications/
usr/share/icons/
usr/share/apport/
usr/share/boot-sav/
usr/share/doc/
usr/share/
usr/bin/
usr/
etc/apport/crashdb.conf.d/
etc/apport/
etc/
docs/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd boot-repair_3.193.7.orig
bash: cd: boot-repair_3.193.7.orig: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Why don't you just install via apt-add-repository and apt-get? 

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

Comment: You say you downloaded it to the downloads directory? Try running `cd Downloads` before running your commands.

Comment: Yes, tried to install from the repository. After first line of command everything looks good. After the second line of command: "Reading package lists ... Done"  Then: "Building depency treee" then: "Reading state information ... Done" then: "E: Unable to locate package boot-repair"

Comment: @Seth Thanks. Tried "cd Downloads" and go through the commands. After first line of command everything looks good. Then "bash: cd: boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz: Not a directory"

Comment: Is there a way to post the Terminal output in the comments in my response to the solutions you guys suggest?

Comment: @monto Just edit it into your question and then comment under the respective answer, pointing them to your edit. Now use the command `cd boot-repair_3.193.7.orig`. There shouldn't be `.tar.gz` on the end.

Comment: Wait, is the file in your home directory or the Downloads directory? Added the output of `ls` might help, though you could consider that a privacy issue (it will list everything in the current directory, which would help us with file names, but might also show private folder/files)

Comment: @Seth Thanks. I just did what you suggested. Result: "No such file or directory." Please see the Terminal output above in my Update. I also noticed the second line in the output: ".gitignore" I wonder if that might be anything of concern.

Comment: Nah, `gitignore` isn't an issue. See my comment above.

Comment: @Seth. Yes, just saw your above comment after I posted mine.  I have copied the tar.gz into my Home directory (didn't delete it from Downloads). I don't have private files there since this is a live USB Ubuntu, so it wouldn't save those anyway after shut-down (but thanks for being thoughtful). The ls result: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -ld boot-repair*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 423870 2013-06-06 22:08 boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz

Comment: Strange thing is: I just went to the Dash, then Find Files. Typed in "boot" to see what files come up. Result shows the tar.gz twice under "Recent" and once under "Downloads." The file search didn't even detect it in the Home directory (but I know it's there).

Comment: OK.  You don't need to follow the same instructions as for aircrack.  you should be able to find ./usr/bin/boot-repair under the boot-repair directory you extracted.   However, it isn't fully installed.  Given the current situation, I strongly recommend following one of the apt-get answers.

Comment: @belacqua Yes, I found Home/usr/bin/boot-repair. Do you mean I should use apt-get with Home/usr/bin/boot-repair, or did you mean that I should follow the apt-get answers for installing from the repository? (The repository attempt earlier didn't work.) Please give me exact instructions. Thanks.

Comment: You could try running ./Downloads/usr/bin/boot-repair from a new terminal window. If it requires any additional libraries to run, however, you would be better off making a Live USB of a newer Ubuntu release (13.04 is the latest) and going with the APT solution.

Comment: @Seth, searchfgold6789, belaqua, Emerson Hsieh, et al. I know it's been a couple of weeks since I posted the above question, but still want to thank you all for the good responses and the effort you all put in. It looks like the issue was due to the (now unsupported) version of Ubuntu -- still, I learned quite a bit from all the answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To install boot-repair, follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). To summarize, type in this command instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Boot-repair should automatically install and run. Select "Recommended Repair" when prompted. If your system still does not boot after running boot-repair, come back to Ask Ubuntu and start a new question including the boot script link that boot-repair will give you.

Comment: Well, it would be easier to copy and paste it. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Same thing happened as I noted in above comment, when I used the format you provided. After first line of command everything looks good. After the second line of command: "Reading package lists ... Done" Then: "Building depency treee" then: "Reading state information ... Done" then: "E: Unable to locate package boot-repair"

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment was confusing. I copied and pasted your command as one line (not two) -- the way you posted it. Still the same result as above.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet when you try that? If not, connect and try again. Otherwise can you paste the output of the command to pastebin and give the link?

Comment: Never mind that comment. 11.10 is no longer supported and you won't be able to install the packages needed to satisfy the dependencies for boot-repair. Please make a new Live USB with the latest version of Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows (see links on the side for other OSes) and try again.

Comment: I just did that. With Universal USB installer, I wasn't able to create the live Boot-Repair USB because UUI could not see the iso in the directory. Strange as I also created another live Ubuntu USB, and the same UUI on the same computer in the same directory at the same time could see the Ubuntu iso. Finally, I created the live boot repair USB with LiLi, which booted, but into a format that looked very much like a BIOS (not a GUI), and I have no idea what to do with that. The first screen looked exactly like the first image on this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Comment: Btw, my ubuntu is 11.10, but the live boot-repair USB is for 13.04. I don't know if that has any significance.

Comment: I just realized that I misread your comment yesterday. I see now that you said to make live USB of the latest version of Ubuntu, and then use boot-repair. Ok, I will do that. Thanks for realizing the version issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are under the /home directory in the terminal, not in the Downloads directory.  Because the file is in the Downloads Directory type `cd Downloads` to switch the directories.

But if you want to install Boot-Repair installing it from the Terminal is a better option.

Search for the Terminal in the Dash, then type these 2 commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the same directory as the file when you run the command `tar -zxvf boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz` .

You can autocomplete by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> if you are in the same directory as the file.  I.e., start typing `tar xvfz boo` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>.  If it's there, it will autocomplete into the full filename (or give the possible completions) and save typing as well.

Are you sure you need to use `make` on this at all?  I don't see any source files in the extracted tree.

You don't need to follow the same instructions as for aircrack.  You should be able to find ./usr/bin/boot-repair under the boot-repair directory you extracted.   However, it isn't fully installed as it expects.  Given the current situation, I strongly recommend following one of the apt-get answers.

Comment: Thanks. Just did that. It did autocomplete, although only to "boot-repair" (not the whole file name). After pressing Enter, got the same result as in my original post. Also tried it with completing the whole file name. Same result.

Comment: Try `ls -ld boot-repair*` . Is there more than one file, or directory?  Perhaps you've extracted it already with archive manager?

Comment: There wasn't, but you gave me an idea, and I copied the file into the Home directory. Looks like now it detects it.  ls -ld boot-repair* produced this result:    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 423870 2013-06-06 22:08 boot-repair_3.193.7.orig.tar.gz  Now I tried to run the commands again to install it that I posted in my original post. It looks like the first command unpacks the tar.gz, but following commands give this:    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: I think Seth's comment (off of your question at top) is on target here -- did you cd into the newly extracted directory?  (I.e., `cd boot-repair...`)  The directory won't have the .tar.gz extension.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, tried that. Please see above comments with Seth.

Comment: No, I am not sure about needing to use "make" on this. I was trying to follow instructions I found on another post.